# C++ Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

today my teacher showed me the following example:

```
CFraction operator*(const CFraction &a, const CFraction &b){ 
   CFraction x;
   x.setNumerator(a.getNumerator()*b.getNumerator());
   x.setDenominator(a.getDenominator()*b.getDenominator());
   return x;
}

// ...

void main(){
   CFraction b1,b2(3,7),b3(5,8);
   b2=b1*3;   
   b2=3*b1;  
}
```

He said that the above code would be working fine, but if you change the method to the following:

```
CFraction operator*(CFraction&,CFraction&);
```

it wouldn't work. Why is that?

Hope you can explain it to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read up on const reference binding.

Comment: Try it and the compiler will tell you. Unless you are using MSVC, then it will keep working as an extension I believe.

Comment: It's impossible to have an no const reference to a literal like 3 in your example for calculation of b2.

Answer (score 5):

> it wouldn't work. Why is that?

Let's look into your expression:

```
b2=b1*3;
```

is equal to:

```
b2=operator*(b1,3);
```

as second type is not type of `CFraction` it has to be converted to it ie:

```
b2=operator*(b1,CFraction(3));
```

`CFraction(3)` creates temporary object of type `CFraction`. Temporary is not lvalue so cannot be passed as lvalue reference - `CFraction &` and if you define your function with non const references (aka lvalue references) it would not work in this case.

Comment: Better use the proper term 'bind' (instead of vague 'passed as lvalue reference')

Answer (score 0):

You are basically asking, "why should my arguments be const?"

There is actually a good reason for this in this scenario.  In c++, whenever you have a function argument with a const reference, (amongst other things) it means you can pass in a literal as an argument into that function (assuming the capacity for a type conversion is available).

For example, if you don't use the const reference, you can still do something like:

```
 CFraction b1,b2(3,7),b3(5,8);
 b3=b1*b2;
```

In the prior example, you passed in (non constant) references to objects b1 and b2. That's alright because this expression makes sense.  However, you could not do the following:

```
 CFraction b1,b2(3,7),b3(5,8);
 b3=b1*3;
```

Why?  Because 3 is a literal.  Whenever you don't include the const reference to CFraction, you cannot pass literals into that function as an argument. Using const reference enables you to pass in literal values.

Comment: Unneccessary focus on literals.

Comment: @SergeyA It doesn't make the response incorrect.  This is a supplementary answer to the information already provided by Slava.

Comment: @SergeyA: Seems completely relevant.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, it makes it seems that if not for literal, it would work fine. For example, `static int i; b3 = b1 * i;` - this seems OK? No pesky literals in sight?

Comment: @SergeyA: Discussing A⇒C doesn't prohibit also B⇒C. Yes, this answer could be broader, but the other one does that quite well. This one is specific to the question. I think, in concert, they are both completely appropriate as-is.

Comment: @SergeyA I appreciate your input. I was not intending to suggest that the const reference is only useful when literals are involved, but rather provide a reason why the code example provided by the question's author would not work without the const reference. Your counter example is valid and the point has been received.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, for educational purpose, it would be much better if the author would focus on reference binding rules, rather than go into such a great lengths into one specific implication of those rules. The answer is also factually incorrect: `Whenever you don't include the const reference, you cannot pass literals into that function as an argument.` is total nonsense.

Comment: @SergeyA I edited that text so it is a bit more clear what I meant in this context.